# How to preserve spaces in input fields with awk

Tags: awk, cut, spaces

I'm trying to do something pretty simple but its appears more complicated than expected... 
I've lines in a text file, separated by the comma and that I want to output to another file, without the first field.

Input:

```
echo file1,item,      12345678 | awk -F',' '{OFS = ";";$1=""; print $0}'
```

Output:

```
;item; 12345678
```

As you can see the spaces before 12345678 are kind of merged into one space only.
I also tried with the cut command:

```
echo file1,item,      12345678 | cut -d, -f2-
```

and I ended up with the same result.

Is there any workaround to handle this?

Actually my entire script is as follows:

```
cat myfile | while read l_line
   do
      l_line="'$l_line'"
      v_OutputFile=$(echo $l_line | awk -F',' '{print $1}')
      echo $(echo $l_line | cut -d, -f2-) >> ${v_OutputFile}
   done
```

But stills in l_line all spaces but one are removed. I also created the quotes inside the file but same result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your invocation of the `echo` command you're using to feed `awk` the test data above.  The shell is looking at this command:

```
echo file1,item,      12345678
```

and treating `file1,item,` and `12345678` as two separate parameters to `echo`.  `echo` just prints all its parameters, separated by one space.

If you were to quote the whitespace, as follows:

```
echo 'file1,item,      12345678'
```

the shell would interpret this as a single parameter to feed to `echo`, so you'd get the expected result.

---

Update after edit to OP - having seen your full script, you could do this entirely in `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{ OFS = "," ; f = $1 ; sub("^[^,]*,","") ; print $0 >> f }' myfile
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my edited question because I'm still having trouble to complete my code.

Answer (score 1):

it has nothing to do with awk.  quote the string in your echo:

```
#with quotes
kent$  echo 'a,b,          c'|awk -F, -v OFS=";" '{$1="";print $0}'
;b;          c

#without quotes
kent$  echo a,b,          c|awk -F, -v OFS=";" '{$1="";print $0}' 
;b; c
```

Comment: ok I get it. Thanks for your answer. However my line is store inside a variable so not sure how to quote my string when creating the variable.